# ServiceStack - IAuthRepository vs IUserAuthRepository

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, servicestack

I’ve to configure my web application to use the ServiceStack built-in ApiKeyAuthProvider. I’ve registered in the container the OrmLiteAuthRepository with the IAuthRepository interface but it throws an exception saying that I’ve not registered the IUserAuthRepository.
Could someone explain me the difference?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
Sorry, i've made confusion
The error is

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'ApiKeyAuthProvider requires a registered IAuthRepository'
```

Our AppHost's Configure method is

```
    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("connString", SqlServerDialect.Provider);
        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory);
        container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(_ => new OrmLiteAuthRepository(dbFactory));
        container.Resolve<IUserAuthRepository>().InitSchema();

        var authProvider = new ApiKeyAuthProvider()
        {
            RequireSecureConnection = false
        };

        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] {
                authProvider
            }
        ));
    }
```

Could you explain me the difference between these two interfaces? we can't figure out (ServiceStack v.6.0.2)

Comment: This doesn't sound right, please include your registration code and full Exception StackTrace & version of ServiceStack you're using.

Comment: @mythz as requested, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the [Auth Repository docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/auth-repository#iauthrepository-apis) for examples of correct usage, e.g:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServer2012Dialect.Provider));

container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c =>
    new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));

container.Resolve<IAuthRepository>().InitSchema();
```

The `IAuthRepository` is the minimum interface all Auth Repositories have to implement whilst `IUserAuthRepository` is the extended interface to enable extended functionality to enabled additional features which all ServiceStack built-in Auth Repositories also implement. But you should never need to register or resolve a `IUserAuthRepository`, i.e. they should only be registered against the primary `IAuthRepository` interface.

#### Resolving Auth Repository

If you need to, the Auth Repository can be accessed from `base.AuthRepository` or `base.AuthRepositoryAsync` in your Service where you'll be able to use any `IUserAuthRepository` APIs since they're all available as extension methods on `IAuthRepository`, e.g. This example Service calls the `IUserAuthRepository.GetUserAuth()` method:

```cs
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Get(MyRequest request) => 
        AuthRepository.GetUserAuth(request.UserId);
}
```

Whilst here are the recommended APIs to access the Auth Repository outside of your Services:

```cs
var authRepo = HostContext.AppHost.GetAuthRepository();
var authRepoAsync = HostContext.AppHost.GetAuthRepositoryAsync();
```

Comment: thanks as always. One last thing: as the doc says, if we want to embed the roles inside the UserAuth table we can set the UseDistictRoleTable property to false. With the same snippet, even if you set that property to false, servicestack will create the UserAuthRole table: is it correct? Thanks again @mythz

Comment: @paolot setting it is unnecessary since it's already the default.

Comment: exactly, as the default is false. But we’ve seen that it always create that table. We will try to understand why @mythz

Comment: @paolot Fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/3645e0d5daeea48c6040f8fadedc683ab2dffa73) will let you know when next pre-release with change is on MyGet later today.

Comment: Ok, thanks as always @mythz

Comment: @paolot FYI this is now available in the latest v6.0.3 pre-release package that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).